# ContextMenu Closes Immediately

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

**Total Edit:**

Now I can reproduce my error and I really don't know why it happens. Any help very much appreciated.

I have the following UI:

```
<Canvas>
    <Button Content="Remove and Readd Rectangle" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding Color}" MouseUp="Rectangle_MouseUp" >
                    <Rectangle.Resources>
                        <RaAtt:RaAttached_BindingProxy Data="{Binding}" x:Key="Data"/>
                    </Rectangle.Resources>
                    <Rectangle.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu IsOpen="{Binding Data.IsOpen, Source={StaticResource Data}}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Test"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Rectangle.ContextMenu>
                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```

Now I want to open a ContextMenu via a MouseClick on the Rectangle:

```
private void Rectangle_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ((sender as Rectangle).DataContext as MyRectangle).IsOpen = true;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

It works on every single Rectangle.

When I click the Button I remove and immediately readd a Rectangle:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyRectangle x = Rectangles.FirstOrDefault();
    Rectangles.Remove(x);
    Rectangles.Insert(0, x);
}
```

If I do this on this removed and readded rectangle the ContextMenu opens and immediately closes again.

**Focus log:**

*Start Application:*

```
'KeyboardFocus:' TestNamespace.MainWindow
```

*RightClick:*

```
'KeyboardFocus:' System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu Items.Count:1
'KeyboardFocus:' TestNamespace.MainWindow
```

*Click on Button:*

```
'KeyboardFocus:' System.Windows.Controls.Button: Remove and Readd Rectangle
```

*RightClick:*

```
'KeyboardFocus:' System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu Items.Count:1
'KeyboardFocus:' System.Windows.Controls.Button: Remove and Readd Rectangle
'KeyboardFocus:' System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu Items.Count:1 //Why does this here happen?
'KeyboardFocus:' System.Windows.Controls.Button: Remove and Readd Rectangle
```

Does anyone know why?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Generally, ContextMenu closes after losing active focus (bringing focus to another window, e.g. window with your ItemsControl). You can set StaysOpen property of ContextMenu to "true" to see if it is the case. Otherwise, it means ContextMenu is closed explicitly - IsOpen is set to "false" either explicitly or through binding

Comment: Unfortunately I still could not solve my problem, but now I'm able to reproduce it. Please look to my Update.

Answer (score 0):

You did not include enough of critical info pertinent to the app functionality in your question (instead, plenty of irrelevant XAML formatting stuff), so the answer is sort of generic: you have to look into code-behind mouse event handlers, namely;

`Rectangle_MouseUp` and `Rectangle_MouseDown`.

Hope this may help.

Comment: The problem is i cannot reproduce my error - these two events work correctly.

Comment: Then, how do you expect us to do the remote debugging of your app if the issue isn't even reproducible? I would suggest to mark the answer accepted (folks may just close this question as too broad and unclear) and post another version focused on that event handlers, so we would be able to look into the issue. Best regards,

Comment: Update: I am able to reproduce it! Sorry that i couldn't do it earlier! Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Did you try and debug, maybe there is another UI Element being set to receive focus programmatically which will cause the Context Menu to close? Has happened to me before.

Check the Call Stack.. set some breakpoints..